# How to add access to s3 bucket for userpool

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

Given a bucket defined like this

```
 const documentsBucket = new s3.Bucket(
            this,
            "documents-bucket",
            {
                bucketName: "documents-bucket",
            }
        );
```

and a userpool & client defined like this

```
const userPool = new cognito.UserPool(this, "domain-userpool", {
            mfa: cognito.Mfa.OFF,
            removalPolicy: cdk.RemovalPolicy.DESTROY,
            signInAliases: {
                email: true,
            },
            autoVerify: {
                email: true,
            },
            selfSignUpEnabled: true,
            accountRecovery: cognito.AccountRecovery.EMAIL_ONLY,
        });

const userPoolClient = userPool.addClient(
            "domain-userpool-client",
            {
                disableOAuth: true,
                authFlows: {
                    userPassword: true,
                },
                supportedIdentityProviders: [
                    cognito.UserPoolClientIdentityProvider.COGNITO,
                ],
                accessTokenValidity: cdk.Duration.days(1),
                idTokenValidity: cdk.Duration.days(1),
                refreshTokenValidity: cdk.Duration.days(30),
            }
        );
```

how do I allow users in that userpool, to read from that bucket, in cdk?

I tried defining a iam policy statement, but I don't know how to attach it to the userpool :(

```
const readAccess = new iam.PolicyStatement({
            actions: ["s3:GetObject", "s3:ListBucket"],
            resources: [
                documentsBucket.bucketArn,
                `${documentsBucket.bucketArn}/*`,
            ],
        });
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use IdentityPool to add roles so the authenticated users will be able to access AWS resources. Below Code is for CDK V2 and you would need to use the `@aws-cdk/aws-cognito-identitypool-alpha` package.

```
    const identityPool = new IdentityPool(this, 'IdentityPoolDemo', {
      identityPoolName: 'IdentityPoolDemo',
      authenticationProviders: {
        userPools: [
          new UserPoolAuthenticationProvider({
            userPool,
            userPoolClient: userPoolClient
          })
        ]
      }
    })

    // this identity pool can access s3
    documentsBucket.grantReadWrite(identityPool.authenticatedRole)
    documentsBucket.grantRead(identityPool.authenticatedRole)
```

Comment: Thankl you! Not to be an asshole or anything, but is there a way to do something similar with v1?
I don't have the experience to migrate the whole infrastructure to v2 :(

Comment: Use the @aws-cdk/aws-cognito-identitypool instead of the aplha package The syntax would be same at high level https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v1/docs/aws-cognito-identitypool-readme.html